# Whats wrong with InputStreamReader here?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, datainputstream, inputstreamreader

I have created a Java Shopping Cart App. I have used InputStreamReader class for it. But its showing strange behavoiur. I have already tried Scanner class and Data Input Stream class. But they they do not seem to be fit for this app.

Can anyone please point out whats wrong with this class?

Also as already stated, Scanner class and DIS class tend to skip the user input, same as here while using ISR class ( see Output : Rate ). I am tired of trying every Java user input utility class, and modifying my code again and again.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
//import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Throwable;


public class NewShop {


protected ArrayList<NewItem> ItemList;
ArrayList<NewItem> cartList ;

   // public DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
   // private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  private InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);

 public void addItem() {

    long aCode = 0;
    String aName ="";
    double aRate = 0;
    int aQuantity = 0;
    NewItem foundItem;

    System.out.println("Enter Item code:");
   /* try{
    String adddisString = dis.readLine();}
      catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();} */

    try{
    aCode = isr.read();
      System.out.println("code entered is : " + aCode);
       }
         catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}

    foundItem = search(aCode);
    if (foundItem == null) {
        System.out.println("Item name : ");
        try{
        aName = dis.readLine();
          }
             catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        System.out.println("Rate : "); 
        try{ aRate = isr.read(); }
           catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}

        System.out.println("Quantity : ");
        try{aQuantity = isr.read();}
        catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}


                  NewItem aItem = new NewItem(aName, aRate, aCode, aQuantity);
                  ItemList.add(aItem);
                  }
                  else {
                  System.out.println("Item exists");
                  }


  } 

}
```

Output :

```
shachindratripathi@saurabh-OptiPlex-3010:~/NewJava$ java NewShoppingCart
  New Shop for Items created.
  -----ITEM------
1. Display all items
2. Search items
3. Add items to list
4. Add items to cart
5. Issue item
6. Exit
Choice:
3
Enter Item code:
1
code entered is : 49
Item name : 
apple
Rate : 
Quantity : 
30
1. Display all items
2. Search items
3. Add items to list
4. Add items to cart
5. Issue item
6. Exit
Choice:
1
       code           name           rate          quantity 

        49            apple           10.0           51

                              ************ 
1. Display all items
2. Search items
3. Add items to list
4. Add items to cart
5. Issue item
6. Exit
Choice:
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Could you try to indend your code a bit more and provide a [mcve] please ? (with some data)

Comment: See the "Output" section. I think the expected output is certainly obvious.

Comment: Well, what I see is that `Enter Item code:1 code entered is : 49` is not what you want .. but did you see where it is ?? You are reading a stream byte per byte using `read()`, you get a `char` value, 1 = 49 see a [ASCII table](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjzrK6HnZXWAhXILcAKHVvfCZsQFgglMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.asciitable.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNGy0sM2NN7tRHE7F011IUWgWo6Z3A)

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The `isr.read()` returns the next character of inupt, as an integer, that you put into a `long` variable. The first entered char was `1`, so the variable got its code `49`...

Comment: @AxelH Oh okay. Now i see.

Comment: And why does the program skip to the next line without asking for input for "Rate" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) allow you to read a Stream character per character using `read` that give you a `int`.

That `int` is not the value you a thinking of, it is a `char` representation of a number, so

```
'0' = 48
'1' = 49
...
```

More in this [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

What you probably want to use here is a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) which is more simple in your case or a [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) that give you the possibility to get the full line in a `String`.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = sc.nextInt(); //This will get the next number an parse it in an integer (or throw an exception)
//careful, the <ENTER> is still in the buffer, flush with sc.nextLine(); if needed
sc.close();
```

The reason you got some inputs skipped using `Scanner` is above, when you read a specific type (like `readInt`), the "enter" key is not read, so it remains in the buffer, the next call of `nextLine` will read it. You need to clear that input before you can get the correct value.

```
int i = sc.nextInt(); 
sc.nextLine(); //clear <enter>
String s = sc.nextLine(); //next input
```

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Indeed, a character could be more than one byte so this was badly said! Thanks. Corrected

Comment: Much needed help. Thanks! But can you please throw some light on as to where from did it assign the value '10.0' to "Rate" even if it didn't ask for user input?

Comment: @SHACHINDRATRIPATHI Well, you use a deprecated [`DateInputStream.readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine()), and I don't believe this class is good for text input. But the method point you to `BufferedReader`, just listen to the documentation ;) Basicly, `enter` is equivalent to `0x13 0x10` character, it used `0x13` to find the "new of line", leaving `0x10` in the buffer, value use on the next `read()` (the one for rate). Explaining the value you got

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Reader`s you have to convert any non-string value yourself.
`DataInput`s uses binary format, not suitable for user input.

Thus your easiest solution would be `Scanner`, so try something like this:

```
public class NewShop
{
  protected ArrayList<NewItem> ItemList;
  ArrayList<NewItem> cartList ;
  private Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  public void addItem()
  {
    long aCode = 0;
    String aName ="";
    double aRate = 0;
    int aQuantity = 0;
    NewItem foundItem;
    System.out.println("Enter Item code:");
    try
    {
      aCode = in.nextLong(); // this reads the to the first char that is not part of the 
      in.nextLine();         // long value, so we need to read till the end of the line...
      System.out.println("code entered is : " + aCode);
      foundItem = search(aCode);
      if (foundItem == null)
      {
        System.out.println("Item name : ");
        aName = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Rate : "); 
        aRate = in.nextDouble();
        in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Quantity : ");
        aQuantity = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        NewItem aItem = new NewItem(aName, aRate, aCode, aQuantity);
        ItemList.add(aItem);
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("Item exists");
      }
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  } 
}
```

Also removed the inner `try-catch`es as if any value is wrong, it is not going to work later...

Comment: Oh, is not there a comment at the first one?

Comment: In a comment ;) I don't read the full code so can't see it (especially with a big code) but I guess this would be enough for newbie.

Answer (score -1):

You do:

```
aCode = isr.read();
```

which returns you an Int Value (See [Ascii-Table](http://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.htm)) of the first character you put in.
So for the "1" you put in, you'll get the Ascii Code of "1", which is 49.

If you want to read Strings with InputStreamReader it can be done like this:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in)
int c;
String input = "";
while((c = isr.read()) != -1){
        input+= (char) c;
}
```

But you would get better and easier results if you use a Scanner for this kind of stuff, see @AxelH answer for this.

Comment: And about `input : 30` ?

Comment: You'll get the first character returned as Int, which is "51" for "3"

Comment: That's a problem... ;)

Comment: Thank you. Any suggestion about which method to use for ISR class here so that i can get expected output?

Comment: @SHACHINDRATRIPATHI I would strongly suggest you to use Scanner or BufferedReader ... But if you insist in using ISR to read Strings. You would need something like this: See updated Answer.